# Литература о Expression Trees in C#

Tags: c#, книги, linq

Добрый день, уважаемые Хешкодовцы =)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, толстую книжку про Dynamic Expression Trees в C#.
Или хотя бы блог, где все подробно описано.
Буду очень благодарен.

Здесь я уже был: [Dynamic Queries with LINQ](http://blog.zwezdin.com/ru/96/print).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги по C# и другая литература](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдельной книжки не видел, но во многих упоминаются, как часть отдельных глав.

Здесь есть примеры

```
http://www.linqpad.net/
http://www.albahari.com/ в частности http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
```